# how to fix "cannot import name 'imresize' error while this function importing from scipy.misc?

Tags: python, scipy, image-resizing

I'm using google colab for running python code and trying to downscale images.

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage import data, io, filters
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from numpy.random import randint
from scipy.misc import imresize
import os
import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.switch_backend('agg')


# Takes list of images and provide LR images in form of numpy array
def lr_images(images_real , downscale):

    images = []
    for img in  range(len(images_real)):
        images.append(imresize(images_real[img],[images_real[img].shape[0]//downscale,images_real[img].shape[1]//downscale], interp='bicubic', mode=None))
    images_lr = array(images)
    return images_lr
```

It should downscale the images but show this error.

> from scipy.misc import imresize ImportError: cannot import name
>   'imresize'

Comment: `imresize` has been removed from scipy as of version 1.3, as it is a duplicate of functionality available elsewhere - specifically, the Pillow module.

Answer (score 6):

install scipy 1.1.0 by :

```
pip install scipy==1.1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

This work for me...
In the imports i changed this:

```
from scipy.misc import imresize
```

for this:

```
from skimage.transform import resize
```

and example of the implementation i changed:

this:

```
img = imresize(img, (150, 150, 3)).astype('float32')/255.
```

for this:

```
img = resize(img, (150, 150, 3)).astype('float32')/255.
```

*i hope this will help you too...*

Comment: This won't work if size are int (1d)

Answer (score 3):

It is deprecated.
Use **cv2** resize function instead

```
import cv2
size = (80,80)
cv2.resize(img, size)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pillow as suggested in the comments. The changes for your code would be as mentioned below:

```
import PIL

images.append(np.array(PIL.Image.fromarray(images_real[img]).resize( 
      [images_real[img].shape[0]//downscale, 
    images_real[img].shape[1]//downscale],resample=PIL.Image.BICUBIC)))
```

If your image is represented as a float you will get an error saying "Cannot handle this data type". In which case you need to convert the image to uint format like this:

```
images.append(np.array(PIL.Image.fromarray( 
    (images_real[img]*255).astype(np.uint8)).resize( 
    [images_real[img].shape[0]//downscale, 
    images_real[img].shape[1]//downscale],resample=PIL.Image.BICUBIC)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

`skimage.transform.resize`

https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_rescale.html

First, import resize:

`from skimage.transform import resize`

Then pass in the image, x/y size values (half the original in this example) and anti-aliasing set to true to prevent aliasing artifacts:

`image_resized = resize(image, (image.shape[0] // 2, image.shape[1] // 2), anti_aliasing=True)`

Comment: Can you put some example?

Answer (score 0):

**imresize** is not available after `1.3.0`.

You can use `Image.resize from PIL`.

install pilow:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Then import

```
from PIL import Image.resize as imresize
```

Comment: importing Image.resize won't work at least for PIL 9.1.0. You should import Image first and then call resize for the object. Check documentation here: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=resize#PIL.Image.Image.resize

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and solve like this:

```
import scpy
```

and the used the functio as it is scipy.misc.imresize(args)
Paulo

Comment: It won't work if scipy version doesn't have the imresize function